# Adding a classname to td (column) of the datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables, classname

I want to add a class to my `<td>` tags in my table. Here is my code

```
var dtVouchers = $('#tblVouchers').DataTable();
 dtVouchers.row.add([
                     '<span>'+text+'</span>',
                       '<span>'+data._voucherCode+'</span>',
                         ....                         
                     ]).draw( true );
```

and here is the my result

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="sorting_1"><span>Valid</span></td>
    <td><span>be6875f9-5af7-4</span></td>
</tr>
```

but I would like to haves something

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="vocuherrow sorting_1"><span>Valid</span></td>    
    <td class="vocuherrow"> <span>dd4ce858</span></td>
</tr>
```

I've tried "addClass" but it adds the class to my `<tr>` (row) not `<td>` (column)

So, my question is how to add "**vocuherrow**" as a classname to my each column?

**Edit:** I prefer the add class while I am addding rows.. not seperatetly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`columnDefs.className`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) option, like this:

```
var dtVouchers = $('#tblVouchers').DataTable({
   columnDefs : [{
      targets: '_all',
      className: 'vocuherrow'
   }]
});
```

Following **demo** illustrates the concept:

```js
//src data
const srcData = [
  {voucher: 'dd4ce858', status: 'valid'},
  {voucher: 'dabce769', status: 'valid'},
  {voucher: '4bdacef5', status: 'valid'},
];

//datatables initialization
dtVouchers = $('#tblVouchers').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
    data: srcData,
    columns: ['voucher', 'status'].map(header => ({title: header, data: header})),
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: '_all',
    className: 'vocuherrow'
   }
  ]
});
```

```css
tbody .vocuherrow {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="tblVouchers"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got the following error: DataTables warning: table id=tblVouchers - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: You should use above code **instead** your `$('#tblVouchers').DataTable()` within `var dtVouchers` assignment

Comment: thank you for the anwser and sorry for the late reply. Well I copied and pasted from your code but does not work. I got the same error! @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg

Comment: That error basically means that you're trying to execute `$('#tblVouchers').DataTable(...)` more than once in your code, so, please, make sure you don't.

Comment: @ertan2002 : mind the example I have appended to my answer, where I apply custom CSS by the class name and use that code in action.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#tblVouchers').find('td').addClass('vocuherrow');
```

or you can leave class 'vocuherrow' on tr and
use

```
tr.vocuherrow  td
```

or similar in your css selects, which I vould normally prefere

Comment: is it not possible to do this while I am creating the rows?

Comment: if DataTable plugin provides such on option .. otherwise you can always to it after plugin init as above. haven't used this plugin, so I can't tell you about its options

Comment: thank you for the reply. I've found addClass method but its for complete row not for row's children (columns)

Comment: well, then you've answered your own question

Comment: maybe there is another way to do it :)